# How to connect CC1101 to Esp32?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, spi

I am building a custom board for [CC1101](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1101.pdf). Basically I only copy the schematic from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1101.pdf).
[image]

I understand SI is the MOSI, SO is the MISO.

However what is the SCLK pin? Is it the CLK or SCL?

And is CSn the SS pin? If not, which one is the SS pin?

Comment: doesn't the datasheet show timing diagrams?

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: there should be a diagram that shows a relationship between SCLK, SI and SO ... see if it matches the SPI timing diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is using the SPI interface so this would be how i would wire it up:

[image: Wiring diagram for esp32 and cc1101]

Note I am using the hardware SPI lines, not the VSPI ones.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. what is the difference between SPI and VSPI? would that change anything programatically appart from obviously using different PIN number in the code?

Comment: HPSI stands for Hardware SPI. VSPI stands for Virtual SPI. Hardware SPI are the SPI pins assigned in the design of the chip. Virtual SPI pins aren't really SPI pins but they can be used as SPI pins but the code has to tell them how to behave as SPI pins. It doesn't matter which ones you use as long as you specify which ones you use in the code.